# the second php form disappears when second submit button is pressed but the first form remains

Tags: php, html, forms

The first form asks for a Customer ID.
When that is obtained the Customer ID details are obtained from a database and displayed.
The second form allows the user to amend the customer details.
But when the second form submit button is pressed the second form disappears while the first form remains. I need the second form to remain also.
Why does this happen?
I have read answers relating to this question but still cannot resolve it.
Here is sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <br>
    <label>Enter Customer ID <input type="number" name="cust" min="1" autofocus/></label>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit"/><br>
</form>

<?php
function goprintcust($custno) {
    echo "<br>"."Customer ".$custno." details are now listed here.....changes will be made below below"."<br>"; getnextform();
}

function getnextform() {
?>
<table>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        <tr>
            <td><label>New Company Name:</td><td> <input type="text" name="newcompname"/></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>New Address1 :</td>
            <td>  <input type="text" name="newaddress1"/></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>New Address2 :</td><td>  <input type="text" name="newaddress2"/></label></td>
        </tr>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>New Address3 :</td>
    <td>  <input type="text" name="newaddress3"/></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>New E-mail :</td>
    <td>  <input type="text" name="newemail"/></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>New Website :</td>
    <td>  <input type="text" name="newwebsite"/></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>New Phone no :</td>
    <td>  <input type="text" name="newphoneno"/></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit"/></td>
</tr>
<br>
</table>
</form>
<?php $y=0;
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST["submit1"])) {
        $custno = $_POST["cust"];
        goprintcust($custno);
    }
    if (isset($_POST["submit2"])) {
        echo "Customer changes updated";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?
Karl

Comment: This happens because your conditions at the bottom are not making it happen. Change your `if` conditions to accommodate what you are saying.

Comment: No offense Karl, but this code is not readable. It took me two read troughs to note that `getnextform()` is printing html. Just don't do it this way, split HTML code from PHP code and for the love of readability... use indentation. And 2 seconds after I posted this, someone fixed it. <3 SO

Comment: Your html does not seem to be matching up in that you have too many close tags in some spots and your table formation should have `<td colspan="2">stuff</td>` when you only want one cell, etc. As you have it, your html is all messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `getnextform();` to your `if (isset ($_POST["submit2"]))`

and assuming you want the form pre-filled with the submitted data for easy edit, then use the `value` attribute of the input with an `isset` ternary.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<br>
<label>Enter Customer ID <input type="number" name="cust" min="1" autofocus/></label>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit"/><br>
</form>

<?php
function goprintcust($custno) {echo "<br>"."Customer ".$custno." details are now listed here.....changes will be made below below"."<br>"; getnextform();}

function getnextform() {
?>
<table>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

<tr><td><label>New Company Name:</td><td> <input type="text" name="newcompname" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['newcompname'])?$_POST['newcompname']:''?>"/></label></td></tr>

<tr><td><label>New Address1 :</td><td>  <input type="text" name="newaddress1" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['newaddress1'])?$_POST['newaddress1']:''?>"/></label></td></tr>

<tr><td>New Address2 :</td><td>  <input type="text" name="newaddress2" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['newaddress2'])?$_POST['newaddress2']:''?>"/></label></td></tr></td></tr>

<tr><td><label>New Address3 :</td><td>  <input type="text" name="newaddress3" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['newaddress3'])?$_POST['newaddress3']:''?>"/></label></td></tr>

<tr><td><label>New E-mail :</td><td>  <input type="text" name="newemail" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['newemail'])?$_POST['newemail']:''?>"/></label></td></tr>

<tr><td><label>New Website :</td><td>  <input type="text" name="newwebsite" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['newwebsite'])?$_POST['newwebsite']:''?>"/></label></td></tr>

<tr><td><label>New Phone no :</td><td>  <input type="text" name="newphoneno" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['newphoneno'])?$_POST['newphoneno']:''?>"/></label></td></tr>

<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit"/></td></tr><br>
    </table>
</form>
<?php $y=0;     }


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST' ) {
if (isset ($_POST["submit1"])) {$custno=$_POST["cust"]; goprintcust($custno);}
if (isset ($_POST["submit2"])) {echo "Customer changes updated";getnextform();}
                     }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked. I have never heard of that 'getnextform()' statement. Where can I get information like that (besides W3Schools.com) ?

Comment: If it worked, upvote and accept as answer. `getnextform()` is your OWN function **you** defined